# Transform geometry_msgs/TransformedStamped() to sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 on rospy

Tags: rospy, sensor-msgs, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people,

I have a geometry_msgs/TransformedStamped() vector which I am trying to translate to sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.
I have looked aroun in the rospy api docs but nothing clear comes out strking.

Question: Has anyone ever used rospy to do this sort of transformation in the past? Example codes/pointing to api references would be helpful.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244992/transform-geometry_msgs/transformedstamped()-to-sensor_msgs/pointcloud2-on-rospy/) by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2016-10-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-05**:
What is it exactly that you are trying to do, and what is the end result you are after? A transform cannot be meaningfully 'translated' into a point cloud, afaict.

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2016-10-05**:
Data is from vicon_bridge package w/each marker packed into a geometry/TransformStamped() msg. I'm trying to stream the markers' world position to move-it as a sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 msg. I wrote a basic rospy code that picks the vector3() translation information but the pcl doens't show directions

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2016-10-05**:
Wondering if I should somehow include the rotation information in the pcl code so i can see the rotation of the clouds when an object moves. Code is here: https://github.com/SeRViCE-Lab/superchicko/blob/devel/superchick_cloud/src/superchick_cloud.py

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-05**:
So you're creating point clouds from scratch, based on TF data coming from the vicon system?

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2016-10-05**:
Yes. I have the code here: https://github.com/SeRViCE-Lab/superchicko/blob/devel/superchick_cloud/src/cloud.py. For some reason, my clouds are static and never move even when my object changes position.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-06**:
Are you setting the cloud's `frame_id` to the correct values? Without those, they will never be transformed.

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2016-10-06**:
The `frame_id` of the child cloud doesn't matter AFAIK. What matters is that the fixed frame we are transforming into must match that of the markers from vicon. What I eventually did was to use the twist I computed from the four markers in vicon to generate a TransformedStamped msg. This was cont'd

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2016-10-06**:
This was then used in computing the new cloud's tranform with the `do_transform_cloud` object. The code is [here](https://github.com/SeRViCE-Lab/superchicko/blob/master/superchick_cloud/src/cloud.py) if you are interested. It is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been fixed. In the end, what I did was to use the twist I computed from the four markers in vicon to generate a TransformedStamped msg. This was then used in computing the new cloud's tranform with the do_transform_cloud object. The code is [here](https://github.com/SeRViCE-Lab/superchicko/blob/master/superchick_cloud/src/cloud.py) if you are interested.

---

Originally posted by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) with karma: 152 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0